# Can an amateur take a Flash game project and switch the images etc. to make a similar game?

Tags: flash, project

I'm a total amateur to Flash, and was wondering if - given the Flash project of this game > http://www.pointzero.co.jp/metalixtd/index_e.html - how hard would it be to make a similar darker game up from it? Would I easily be able to for example switch the images and use the path direction system that the enemies use to move their path on the board? Would I need to write code? How hopeful is this idea.

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow** as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: There's nothing more to say. As said, I'm wondering if I can switch those enemies(sprites) images to my own ones, including the rest of the images, and if I can use the already made direction system to make them move a certain path on the board, and if coding is required.

Comment: If you have the actual **.FLA** file and original **.AS** files (not decompiled) and also if the sprites are images (png images?) then it might be possible to update with newer same-size images and recompile). To change any movement you will have to know AS3 code.

Comment: It looks to be 3D.......and no I wanted to do a big change.....I guess can't easily then with the current Engine. I wanted to see if I could make this by the way -http://s1318.photobucket.com/user/coolgodboss/media/TD%20design_zps2mcqvdq7.png.html?sort=3&o=8 &&&&&&&& http://s1318.photobucket.com/user/coolgodboss/media/pipe%20examples_zpshjokwjla.png.html?sort=3&o=9

Comment: I understand you now. You want a template for your game. No it won't be possible that easily and it's actually illegal to "adjust" someone else's game & call it your own. I thought they hired you to put old graphics into Photoshop & just change colours or similar task. Also even if you did you need to re-compile the game, the issues / errors that come up will require that you know how AS3 code works. If you want to turn your idea into a game just make the big jump & try or find a team collaborator (try a games forum etc) whereby you do the graphics & they code...

Comment: Well the producer of that game I'm sure is willing to, I had talked to him before~ Anyhow nevermind, I'm so busy with artificial intelligence all I could do is hire the producer, though I don't know if should even, so, eh.. I could use the game to earn money/gain attention~